# How can I get data from one container to another in docker? I am getting ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have been trying for a while to get information from a postgres container to a node container with docker. I used a docker-compose file provided below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'tweets1'
      PGDATA: '/tmp'
  web:
    image: node-app
    ports:
      - "4556:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    links:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - webnet
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh","postgres:5432","--","node","dashboard.js"]
networks:
  webnet:
```

After I run docker-compose up, everything in the log looks fine. Postgres starts first and I actually can access the database using

```
psql -h localhost -p 3030 -U postgres tweets1
```

When I load the node-web app in my browser everything loads perfectly except from the information that should be retrieved from the database. I get the following error in the log of my container:

> {Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 at
>   TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1158:14)
>       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>       syscall: 'connect',
>       address: '127.0.0.1',
>       port: 5432 }

I have been trying to use the **host.docker.internal** in my PG config variable but its not working either. When I check my containers through docker container ps. Both are up and running.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first command:

> psql -h localhost -p 3030 -U postgres tweets1

works on your **host** because you added a port binding when you declared the postgres container. The port binding does not apply to other containers though.

Container -> Container connections require a regular network connection.

You will find that usually the linked containers are declared in the containers' /etc/hosts by docker, using the names you assigned to the containers.

So, while in the `web` container try:

> psql -h **postgres** -p 3030 -U postgres tweets1

**Finally:**

In your code, you should connect to the **postgres** host not localhost.

Comment: Thank you so very much! That was actually the problem I had and got solved by connecting to postgres and not localhost.